# How to add custom success message in Mocha tests?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, should.js

I have a loop inside a test case where I repeat a part of the test for each data sample.

How can I add a custom sucess message indicating that specific data, representing a test case, was sucessful?

For instance, my code is like:

```
it('Should not allow saving bad data: ', async function () {
  let badData = TestDataProvider.allData.invalid;
  for (let i = 0; i < badData.length; i++) {
    let d = badData[i];
    let res = await request.post('/data').send(d);
    let object = null;
    try {
      object = JSON.parse(res.text);
    } catch (e) {
      object = {};
    }
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(206);
    expect(object).not.to.contain.a.property('_id');
    console.log('Verified case: ' + d.testDesc);
  }
});
```

I want the `"Verified case..."` message to appear as successful test runs and not console messages in reports.

The `testDesc` attribute holds test description like: `"Missing field a", "Invalid property b", "Missing field c"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem creating dynamic tests:

```
const allData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json'), 'utf8'));
allData.invalid.forEach((badData) => {
  it('Should not allow saving with: ' + badData.testDesc, async () => {
    let res = await request.post('/data').send(badData);
    let d = null;
    try {
      d = JSON.parse(res.text);
    } catch (e) {
      d = {};
    }
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(206);
    expect(d).not.to.contain.a.property('_id');
  });
});
```